# pyqt5でサブウィンドウからメッセージボックスが開かない

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5

python3.5を使っています。pyqt5を使ってサブウィンドウからメッセージボックスを開きたいです。下が書いたコードです。

サブウィンドウで入力されたものが数値でなかった時にメッセージボックスが出るように書いたつもりです。しかし、メッセージボックスは表示されず、動作を中止してしまいます。

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        makeWindowButton = QPushButton("&make window")
        makeWindowButton.clicked.connect(self.makeWindow)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setText("default:")

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(makeWindowButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def makeWindow(self):
        subWindow = SubWindow(self)
        subWindow.show()

    # サブウィンドウから実行
    def setParam(self, param):
        self.label.setText(param)

class SubWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.w = QDialog(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        label = QLabel()
        label.setText('Sub Window')

        self.edit = QLineEdit()
        self.edit.setText(str(1))

        button = QPushButton('送信')
        button.clicked.connect(self.setParamOriginal)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.w.setLayout(layout)

    # ここで親ウィンドウに値を渡している
    def setParamOriginal(self):
        try:
            text=float(self.edit.text())
            text=str(text)
            self.parent.setParam(self.edit.text())
        except:
            QMessageBox.about(self, "警告", "それは数字ではありません")

    def show(self):
        self.w.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コードを書き換えた結果こうなりました。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
#自分のコードスタイルでは、出自を明らかにしています。なので全部QtWidgetsをつけています。QtGuiとQtCoreは全く使っていないので削除しました。

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=None)

        self.makeWindowButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&make window")
        self.makeWindowButton.clicked.connect(self.makeWindow)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText("default:")

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.makeWindowButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def makeWindow(self):
        subWindow = SubWindow(self)
        subWindow.show()

    # サブウィンドウから実行
    def setParam(self, param):
        self.label.setText(param)

class SubWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        self.w = QtWidgets.QDialog(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setText('Sub Window')

        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.edit.setText(str(1))

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('送信')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.setParamOriginal)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.w.setLayout(layout)

    # ここで親ウィンドウに値を渡している
    def setParamOriginal(self):

        try:
            text=float(self.edit.text())
            text=str(text)
            self.parent.setParam(self.edit.text())
        except:　　　　　　　　　#ここの第一引数に注目！
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self.parent, "警告", "それは数字ではありません")

    def show(self):
        self.w.exec_()
def main():
    try:    
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    except Exception as e:
        print(66,e)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

わたしの環境で動くように変更したうえで、
このようなエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "J:/stack_overflow_question_1.pyw", line 59, in setParamOriginal
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(self, "警告", "それは数字ではありません")

TypeError: about(QWidget, str, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'SubWindow'
```

つまり、`QMessageBox`の第一引数を、`self.parent`と改めれば、コードが
動くようになりました。この第一引数には、ウィジェットが入らなければ
なりません。エラーメッセージにもそのように書いてありますね。
　PySideですが、こちらを参照。
　[QtGui.QMessageBox.about-](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QMessageBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QMessageBox.about)
`SubWindow`クラスは、何らウィジェット系のクラスを継承して
いませんから、`self`をそのまま指定すると、ウィジェットではないものが
第一引数に入れられてしまっているのです。
そのため、`self.parent`と改めて、ウィジェット系のコードを入れれば治り
ました。

Comment: 回答、及び詳しい解説ありがとうございます！質問とは関係ないですが一つ聞きたいことがあります。pyqtを使っていてエラーメッセージが出ず、GUIの動作が停止してしまうことが悩みの種です。回答のようにエラーメッセージが表示される何かいい方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 私もがちゃがちゃ色々やって根本的な原因がわからないのですが、まずは、1.何のエディタを使っているのか。2.`QtWidgets.QApplication`は、どうやら一度コードを実行すると、GUIを閉じたとしても、ずっとコンピューター内部では走っているようです。だから、次にコードを実行するべく実行ボタンを押すと、QtWidgets.QApplication is already active.とかいうエラーが私は出て、ここで動作が停止します。（始めたては、一度実行するごとに、エディタまで落とさなければならなかった。PyQt導入サイトなどでは、これなしでいくらでも動くかのように書いてあり、私だけだと思っていました。）だから、私のコードを見ていただければわかるのですが、try文でエラーを回避しています。最後に、それらをやったうえで上記のようなエラーが出るかどうかですが、上の二つ次第で、エラーが発生する環境が整ったという可能性もあり、確かなことは言えません。まずは私と同じように書いて試してみていただけたらいいかと思います。私もこれはものの本を読んだのをまねて書いたのであり、どうしてこうなるのかをわかっているわけではありません。ちなみに、私はpython3.6,AnacondaのSpyderエディタを利用しています。

Comment: python‌​3.5,AnacondaのSpyderエ‌​ディタを使ってみましたが、`An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.`と表示されてエラーは表示されませんでした。3.6にアップデートしてからもう一度やってみます。

Comment: それは普通にGUIを落として実行をやめたときにでるメッセージです。私の2.のエラーはmain関数内の`try`文なしだと、またGUIを見ようとコードを実行すると、`QApplication is already active`というエラーが出て、2度目以降の実行ができなくなります。できたらならいいんじゃないでしょうか。問題は、`QMessageBox.about()`のエラーをわざと出してみて、出てくれるかどうかですね。そちらのエラーを出してみたいと思われているようですから。

Comment: 仰る通り、try文でエラー表示をプリントさせて、かつわざとエラーを発生させていますが、エラー文は表示されないですね。何はともあれしっかり動作するようになったので感謝です。

Comment: 念のため確認です。ちゃんとコードの要求するように、数字以外の文字をセットして、ボタンを押した後でも、エラーがでないということですね？

Comment: そうですね。本来`float`ではエラーが起こる文字列をセットして実行していますがエラーを吐かずに動作を停止します。ちなみに普段はAnacondaで一緒にインストールされるpython shellでpyqtを使っていました。こちらではエラーが出ると動作を停止してGUIが閉じてしまいます。SpyderではGUIが閉じることはないもののやはりエラーを吐くことなく動作を停止してしまいます。

Comment: 以前Spyderを使っていた時、コンソール上にmatplotlibのアニメーションが表示されなくて、それ以来使っていませんでしたが、Pyqtに関しては非常に使いやすいですね。有益な情報ありがとうございます！